# SQL select from 2 tables where values in the second table might be absent

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 tables:

1. Students with columns (student id, firstname, lastname) and
2. grades (gradeid, studentid, grade).

How can I select ALL students including those that do not have grades (hence, they are not in the grades tables).
For example:

Students

```
100   StudentFN1  StudentLN1
101   StudentFN2  StudentLN2
102   StudentFN3  StudentLN3
```

Grades

```
1   101   90
2   102   70
```

So I want all students to be selected, even student 102 which is not in Grades. Student 102 grade should be empty.

Comment: SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS you are asking them for (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, …). Which is yours?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an outer join:

```
select *
from students
left outer join grades on grades.studentid = students.studentid
order by students.studentid;
```

Comment: This works great. Do you know how I can update also in the same way?

Comment: What would you update? Do you want to get rid of the grades table and add a grade column in the students table instead? Then you can `update students set grade = (select grade from grades where grades.studentid = students.studentid)` and drop the grades table afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is a *left join*

```
select 
student.*, grade_id, grade
from students
left join grades 
  on students.student_id = grades.student_id
```